# how to create android listview like android google chrome tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I need to create listview like in this picture. The listview item go over each other like google chrome tabs.. I can move up or down listview item... Could anyone tell me a good advice or tell me examples how should I do this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Good luck with that custom control!

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think that this is a ListView per say. On the other hand, you can always find the source code for Chrome and have a look :D

Comment: like what picture? you didn't add any picture

Comment: is anyone had solution for this, i have similar layout.

Answer (score 1):

You need an iOS passbook style component like [CardWalletView](https://github.com/LivioGama/CardWalletView)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create some accordions type control

Here is a link which will help you

http://android-puremvc-ormlite.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-simple-accordion-panel.html

when you close the previous view you will not animate that view to the end you have to keep some margin of 2 to 3 pixels to show view as you want

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is you should create some view and use drag and drop... But also you have to some Math calculation... Try this maybe you can get something

Answer (score 0):

**Expanding list views** may help you with that. I assume that your list view will essentially *expand on click and shift everything below* the selected area downwards revealing only the content of that selected tab.

Expanding list views utilize the **parent-child** methods that would allow you to create a very rough view of what you are showing. Styling and customizing those rough layouts afterwards could very well allow you to get that look you're looking for.

Here are some links that might be useful. 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html