# Create custom ListView with shadow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

How could I create custom `ListView` like shown in this picture. I know I can make this happen with help of `ScrollView` and Layouts, but I need to do as a `ListView`.
Each listview item go over each other. 
[image]

Comment: What do u mean with  "Each listview item go over each other"?

Comment: I mean that each item is above from his previous item like in picture.

Comment: You have to make custom drawable using xml with top corner rounded. And set it to Custom Listview row. Simple :-)

Comment: Like the colors like rainbow!!

Comment: @user370305 it's not that easy because one row background have to be in the following row.

Comment: @RobertoLombardini - Which will be added logic in getView() of Custom Adapter...

Comment: @user370305 Look at the picture, the upper corner of row 2 have the background color of row 1, the upper corner of row 3 have the background color of row 2 and so on. This is not a simple custom row, you have to put something out of the getView that give you the 2 background color in the right order

Comment: @RobertoLombardini - No, on Upper corners there is transparent background in rounded shape which will reflect the previous (above) rows background.

Comment: @user370305 ok, but how do you make the two row overlap each other?

Comment: Its a logic of getView(). Which returns next row at some top margin in negative.

Comment: @user370305 you're right but the problem is how we can manage this.

Comment: i don't know if it works but it sounds correct ^^. @fish40 try that way

Comment: @RobertoLombardini what do you mean 'try that way'?

Comment: when u set the layout of your row u set `android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"` and something should happen ^^

Comment: another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464258/how-to-create-android-listview-like-android-google-chrome-tab but no answer... :(

Comment: @pankaj kumar that seems more complex than this case

Comment: @RobertoLombardini I tried unfortunately it doesn't work (( but thanks anyway.

Comment: @PankajKumar I working on this already days I can't find good solution. I posted it again maybe someone could help me.

Comment: @fish40 ok. Actually I remember the pic attached and thought this may answer before, but when I got the given link, sad. :( . Hope you will find the solution...

Comment: just one last things, do you use `RelativeLayout` as row layout? Because without relative negative margin doesn't work

Comment: yes I do. I use relativeLayout.

Comment: :( then i don't know how to do it, i'll make some try at launch, i hope to find out something usefull

Comment: @RobertoLombardini - My answer is what I talked about.

Comment: @user370305 i see, nice one ^^. Anyway, for the next time, please be more accurate when u answer someone, even if it is only a comment, because somethings that is easy for u might not be obvious for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for trying help me to solve this issue. I look every answer here and finally get i want. I think it will be better I put my code here so maybe someone it will be helpful. The only difference is that my created listview has also shadow in it.

Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:my_font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.Helix.android.SmartBonus"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_bg"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageview">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/companyImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/secret_logo_small"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/companyImageView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                my_font:ttf_name="300"
                android:text="Салон кросаты"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/companyImageView"
                android:layout_below="@id/companyDescription"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                my_font:ttf_name="300"
                android:text="Secret"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyPercentText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/companyPercent"
                my_font:ttf_name="700"
                android:text="-20"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@id/companyPercent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                my_font:ttf_name="300"
                android:text="%"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/companyPercentImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/companyPercent"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/percentage_devider"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyDistance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/companyPercentImage"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="#A57F1C"
                my_font:ttf_name="300"
                android:text="7m"/>
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/checkingButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/companyDistance"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:background="@drawable/green_button_bg"
                android:visibility="gone">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    my_font:ttf_name="300"
                    android:text="Check-in"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/checkin_point_color"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    my_font:ttf_name="300"
                    android:text="@string/ten_point"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/slak"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

adapter.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final Discount discount = getItem(i);
        Discount prev_discount = null;
        if (i > 0){
            prev_discount = getItem(i-1);
        }

        if (view == null){
            final LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.discount_data_item, viewGroup, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.logo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.companyImageView);
            viewHolder.name = (SmartBonus_TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.companyName);
            viewHolder.description = (SmartBonus_TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.companyDescription);
            viewHolder.percent =  (SmartBonus_TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.companyPercentText);
            viewHolder.distance =  (SmartBonus_TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.companyDistance);
            viewHolder.mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            viewHolder.secondLayaout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.secondLayout);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (i == 0){
            viewHolder.mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
            setRoundedBackground(viewHolder.secondLayaout, Color.parseColor(discount.getBackgroundColor()));
        } else {
            viewHolder.mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(prev_discount.getBackgroundColor()));
            setRoundedBackground(viewHolder.secondLayaout, Color.parseColor(discount.getBackgroundColor()));

        }


        return view;
    }

    private void setRoundedBackground(View view,int color){
        final GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground().mutate();
        gradientDrawable.setColor(color);
        gradientDrawable.invalidateSelf();
    }
```

Here is the result
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This may help you
[List view with custom view items with partially overlaps (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551501/list-view-with-custom-view-items-with-partially-overlaps-android)

Comment: it's not about colors. I mean the next listItem is above from previous item.

Comment: That example use ScrollView (((

Answer (score 2):

*I have this code like your Requirement. List may overlap by reducing the dividerheight to minus value*

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="-5dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

*Then add background color to adapter according to the position.*

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

    if(position % 2 ==0){
        vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listselector_1);
    }else if(position % 3 ==0){
        vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listselector_2);
    }else{
        vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listselector_3);
    }

    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
    duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

*Otherwise you can use listselector images also as your requirement*

Answer (score 0):

You should override [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method.

Sample code:

```
View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Object data = getItem(positon);
    //usually data object should have type property
    if(data.type == TYPE1){
        return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_xml1, null);
     }else (data.type == TYPE2){
        return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_xml2, null);
     }else{
        return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_xml, null);
     }
};
```

Note:You should reuse **convertView** object for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, As I have sort of time I manage to write few steps to achieve your task.

```
1. Make Custom drawable using xml in drawable folder with top corners have radius..

2. Now in your Listview attributes just define negative divider height 
   Like, android:dividerHeight="-20dp"

3. Set the Custom Drawable as a background of List row in getView().
```

Also its nice if you able to set color to drawable at dynamically for list row. (In `getView()` of Custom Adapter).

This what I have achieved from above steps:

[image]